# php replace string of known length but unknown characters

Tags: php, regex

If I have a string that begins `foo` and is 8 characters in length so looks like `foo?????` What pattern will I need to replace it using `preg_replace()`?

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: `''` nothing empty string sorry should have said

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) >> jump to quantifiers and "any character"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/foo.{5}/', '',  $string)
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by matching:

`/(foo)(.{5})/`

and replacing with

`''`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/fX7tV9

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('^/foo.{5}$/','',$string)
```

This should fit your needs.

Search in $string for

```
^  //Begin of the line
foo //Text your searching for
. //Some character
{5} //5 times the dot as character.
$ // end of line
```

and replace it with '' (second parameter)